# eclipse, set up android application

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm studying this tutorial now:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipse-android/

I got an error says "project contains error" when running the code. But I didn't find any error mark in my project. What happened? Thank you very much!

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Try to restart 
1. restart eclipse
2. clean your project
3. fix project setup

Comment: Why is there an R.java file in your `src` directory?  That file is generated by the platform, not you.  It is probably interfering with the real R.java file in your `gen` directory.  Remove the file from `src` and Eclipse will be happier.

Comment: There's a big red exclamation mark on your project. There's a view in Eclipse called Error Log (Windows -> Show View) that will probably give you more info. Have you selected a target for your project?

Comment: @Barak, that could definitely be the reason provided he is using Android newer than 1.5. Prior to 1.5 R.java was locatied in src folder

Comment: Try checking console or error log (Window->Show View...) for more details of the error.

Comment: Ah, Thanks @Robin, I didn't start with Android until a bit later than that, so was unaware.  However, I see 4.1.2 in there, so that's likely the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click in your project - Properties - Java Build Path - and then you will see the error, so you just have to delete the error and then clean your project

Answer (score 0):

There is an R.java file in your `src` directory, and while it used to go there in previous versions (as I just learned), it doesn't belong there any more.

That file is generated by the platform, not you, and should appear in the `gen` directory.

The copy in your `src` directory is probably interfering with the real R.java file in your `gen` directory. Remove the file from `src` and Eclipse will be happier.